# RMI client UnmarshalException

Tags: java, rmi

my project is client/server that client send an object to the server and server respond, all that by RMI

client project

// the interface

```
public interface RMI_INTERFACE extends Remote
{

public int Add(Employee e) throws RemoteException;
}
```

// the class that i need to send it

```
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
int ID;

String Name;

int Salary;

public Employee(int id,String name,int salary) 
{
    ID=id;

    Name =name;

    Salary=salary;
}


}
```

//the client

```
public class RMI_CLIENT 
{

public RMI_CLIENT() 
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {


         String name = "RMI_INTERFACE";
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost",5000);
        RMI_INTERFACE si = (RMI_INTERFACE) registry.lookup(name);

        int ii;

        for (Integer i=0 ;i<10;i++)
        {
            Employee e= new Employee(i,  "employee"+i.toString() , i*1000+100);

            ii=si.Add(e);
            System.out.println(ii);

        }

       // int pi = si.Get_Salary(s);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getCause());
    }
}
}
```

//server project

//the interface
    public interface RMI_INTERFACE extends Remote
    {

```
public int Add(Employee e) throws RemoteException;
}
```

//class that i will send it and receive it
    public class Employee implements Serializable
    {
    int ID;

```
String Name;

int Salary;

public Employee(int id,String name,int salary) 
{
    ID=id;

    Name =name;

    Salary=salary;
}


}
```

//class to hold all received objects
    public class Maneger {

```
static Employee [] employee_arr = new Employee[10];

static int i=0;

Maneger (Employee e)
{
    employee_arr[i]=e;

    i++;

}

public int Get_Index ()
{
    return i;
}
}
```

//the server
    public class RMI_SERVER extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMI_INTERFACE
    {

```
RMI_SERVER() throws RemoteException 
{
      super();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here         

        String name = "RMI_INTERFACE";
        RMI_INTERFACE si = new RMI_SERVER();        
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( 5000 );
         registry.rebind(name, new RMI_SERVER() );
        System.out.println("Server is running ...");




    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ComputeEngine exception:");
    }



}

@Override
public int Add(Employee e) throws RemoteException {

    Maneger m =new Maneger(e);

    return m.Get_Index();

}


}
```

when i run client appear this error : java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object

Answer (score 0):

You've changed the remote object or the remote interface, but you haven't recompiled and redeployed all the affected .class files.